# multi-page tables with description text in IEEE format

Tags: longtable, overleaf, ieee

An issue with the IEEE LaTeX template. When I use the longtable environment for a table, it ends up overlapping into the adjacent two-column format after completion.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\caption{The following table summarizing snoRNA expression across cancer types was adapted from Huang et al. (2022):} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{snoRNA Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Cancer Type}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Expression}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Mechanism, Pathway, or Target}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Functions}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Reference}}\\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{snoRNA Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Cancer Type}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Expression}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Mechanism, Pathway, or Target}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Functions}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Reference}}\\ \hline 
    \endhead

\hline \multicolumn{6}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
SNORA 18L5 &    Hepatocellular carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     p53 &   Increase ribosome biogenesis, facilitate ribosomal RNA maturation, and alter the localization of RPL5 and RPL11, allowing for increased MDM2-mediated proteolysis of p53 and cell cycle arrest &    \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA15 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA21 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Be involved in epithelial cell differentiation, morphogenesis, and cell adhesion &  \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Gallbladder cancer &    Down-regulation &   Ecadherin, N-cadherin, vimentin, c-Myc and Cyclin D1 &  Inhibit GBC cell migration and invasion by down-regulating the EMT process of GBC cells &   \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Gastric cancer &    Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Be associated with distant metastasis and lymph node metastasis in GC patients &    \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA23 &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Pancreatic ductal adenocarcinoma &  Up-regulation &     SYNE2 &     Promote PDAC cell survival and invasion, and growth and metastasis of xenograft tumors through modulation of ribosome biogenesis &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA24 &   "Colorectal
carcinoma & "   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA26 &   Sarcomas &  Up-regulation &     Rap1, Hippo, MAPK, sphingolipid, TGF-b, Wnt &   Enrich in cell differentiation, regulation of cell development, regulation of transcription, cell ecell signaling, and activation of protein kinase B activity &    \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA3 &    Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA31 &   Leukemia &  Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA36B &  Head and neck squamous cell carcinoma &     Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA41 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA42 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Increase cell proliferation, tumorigenicity, migration, invasion, and anoikis resistance in colon cancer cells &    \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Be associated with the expression of stem cell-core transcription factors in lung tumor-initiating cells &  \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Prostate cancer &   Up-regulation &     Metabolic pathways &    Enhance prostate cancer cell viability, migration, and EMT &    \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA47 &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA52 &   Hepatocellular carcinoma &  Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Function as a potential diagnostic and prognostic marker for HCC &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA55 &   Prostate cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   biomarker for HCC patients Be involved in the cell-to-cell signaling and interaction &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA6 &    Leukemia &  Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA62 &   Leukemia &  Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA65 &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA68 &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA70F &  Leukemia &  Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA71A &  Breast cancer &     Up-regulation &     ROCK2, TGF-b &  Promote breast tumor growth and enhance metastasis of breast cancer &   \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     LBP, NF-kappa B, Toll-like receptor &   Promote CRC cell migration and invasion &   \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA71B &  Breast cancer &     Up-regulation &     EMT &   Promote the proliferation, migration, and invasion of breast cancer cells with different metastatic abilities &     \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA71C &  Leukemia &  Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA73B &  Sarcomas &  Up-regulation &     Oxidative phosphorylation, metabolic pathways, NF-kappaB, stimulatory C-type lectin receptor &  Enrich in cell cycle, regulation of protein ubiquitination, and RNA metabolic process &     \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA74A &  Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA78 &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA7A &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORA7B &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD104 &  Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Lead to the disorder of rRNA methylation, and also lead to the decrease of cell volume and the repair speed of damaged protein &    \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD105 &  Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD105B &     Gastric cancer &    Up-regulation &     ALDOA/C-Myc Pathway &   Be associated with tumor size, differentiation, and pathological stage in GC as well as affect proliferation, migration, and invasion in multiple GC cell lines &   \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD110 &  Leukemia &  Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD112-114 &  Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD113-1 &    Hepatocellular carcinoma &  Down-regulation &   MAPK/ERK, TGF-b &   Function as a tumor suppressor role in HCC and be important as a potential diagnostic and therapeutic target for HCC &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD114-17 &   Head and neck squamous cell carcinoma &     Up-regulation &     PI3K/AKT, the ECM receptor &    Be involved in the regulation of cell adhesion, invasion, and metastasis &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD116-18 &   Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD126 &  Hepatocellular carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     FGFR2, PI3K-AKT &   Promote the progression of HCC &    \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD12B &  Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD12C/SNORD106 &     Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD14E &  Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Be involved in systemic lupus erythematosus, alcoholism, viral carcinogenesis, transcriptional mis-regulation in cancer &   \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD15A &  Breast cancer &     Up-regulation &     p53 &   Compromise tumorigenicity both in vitro and in vivo via activation of p53 &     \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD15B &  Breast cancer &     Up-regulation &     p53 &   Compromise tumorigenicity both in vitro and in vivo via activation of p53 &     \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD17 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Hepatocellular carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     p53 &   Promote the growth and tumorigenicity of HCC cells in vitro and in vivo &   \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD1C &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Involvement of snoRNAs in the regulation of ribosomes, rRNA processing, RNA splicing, and translation regulation &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD22 &   Breast cancer &     Up-regulation &     p53 &   Compromise tumorigenicity both in vitro and in vivo via activation of p53 &     \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD28 &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD33 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD34 &   Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Lead to the disorder of rRNA methylation, and also lead to the decrease of cell volume and the repair speed of damaged protein &    \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD35A &  Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Lead to the disorder of rRNA methylation, and also lead to the decrease of cell volume and the repair speed of damaged protein &    \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD3A &   Head and neck squamous cell carcinoma &     Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD3F &   Head and neck squamous cell carcinoma &     Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Be related to RNA editing &     \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD42A &  Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     20-O-methylation at Uridine 116 of 18S rRNA &   An important snoRNA for the proliferation of leukemic cells &   \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD43 &   Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Lead to the disorder of rRNA methylation, and also lead to the decrease of cell volume and the repair speed of damaged protein &    \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD44 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Down-regulation &   Caspase-dependent pathway, PI3K/Akt &   Inhibit CRC cell proliferation and induced caspase-dependent cell apoptosis &   \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Gliomas &   Down-regulation &   "Caspase-
dependent

apoptosis pathway & "   "Facilitate the apoptosis with
the inhibited proliferation,
invasion, and migration of
glioma cells & "    \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Prostate cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD46 &   Breast cancer &     Downregulation &    Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD46 &   Sarcomas &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Enrich in the regulation of gene expression, DNA replication, DNA repair, cell division, cell cycle, cell proliferation, oxidative phosphorylation, and response to drug &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD47 &   Gliomas &   Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Inhibit glioma cell growth, proliferation, colony formation, invasion, and migration, and induces G2-phase arrest in vivo and in vitro. &   \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD49A &  Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD50 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Down-regulation &   Methylation of C2848 in 28S rRNA &  Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD50(A/B) &  Breast cancer &     Down-regulation &   k-Ras &     Downregulate mitosis-related genes, prolonged mitosis, repressed colony-forming ability, and clinical analyses &    \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD52 &   Hepatocellular carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     CDK1 &  Be associated with the poor prognosis of patients with HCC, acting as a functionally relevant snoRNA in HCC &   \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD55 &   Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD57 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD63 &   Clear cell renal cell carcinoma &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD66 &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD67 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Be involved in systemic lupus erythematosus, alcoholism, viral carcinogenesis, transcriptional mis-regulation in cancer &   \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD73B &  Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD74 &   Prostate cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD76 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Gliomas &   Down-regulation &   pRb &   Arrest glioma cells at the S phase of the cell cycle, which in turn may affect the expression of cell cycle-associated proteins &   \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Hepatocellular carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Wnt/b-catenin &     Suppress cell proliferation by inducing G0/G1 cell cycle arrest and apoptosis &     \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD78 &   Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   "Head and neck
squamous cell
carcinoma & "   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Lung cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Prostate cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD81 &   Prostate cancer &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD87 &   Breast cancer &     Up-regulation &     p53 &   Compromise tumorigenicity both in vitro and in vivo via activation of p53 &     \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD89 &   Breast cancer &     Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Ovarian cancer &    Up-regulation &     Notch1-c-Myc &  Result in increased stemness markers, S phase cell cycle, cell proliferation, invasion, and migration ability in OV and CA cells &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD96A &  Clear cell renal cell carcinoma &   Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD3A &   Breast cancer &     Up-regulation &     p53 &   Trigger a remarkably potent p53-dependent anti-tumor stress response involving the ribosomal proteins uL5 (RPL11) and uL18 (RPL5) &     \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Sarcomas &  Down-regulation &   Unknown &   Enrich in oxidative phosphorylation, regulation of protein ubiquitination, cellular metabolic process, and RNA metabolic process &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SNORD118/ SCARNA9L &    Breast cancer &     Up-regulation &     p53 &   Trigger a remarkably potent p53-dependent anti-tumor stress response involving the ribosomal proteins uL5 (RPL11) and uL18 (RPL5) &     \cite{} \\ \hline
nan &   Hepatocellular carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Wnt/b-catenin &     Inhibit the proliferation of HCC cells by inducing G0/G1 arrest and apoptosis &     \cite{} \\ \hline
SCARNA6 &   Leukemia &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SCARNA22 &  Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline
SCARNA15 &  Colorectal carcinoma &  Up-regulation &     Unknown &   Unproved &  \cite{} \\ \hline


\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

After using this code it overlap one column. I am providing the screenshot of that problem.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! **(i)** please always provide MWE (Minimal working example), a complete small document, which reproduce your problem (if possible), **(ii)** long table can not be inserted in two column document. You need before it change two column document to one column. and after then switch back to two column article. At this can be handy `afterpage` package. However, from showed table image is not seems that you need a `longtable` . If this is a case, than you can insert table in float `table*` which enable tat table span both columns.

Comment: As noted, a compilable MWE would help. Sometimes the problem is caused by loading a conflicting package, but we do not know what document class or packages you are using.